# pick Image from Google Photos crashing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

here is the code where i'm picking image from gallry & its sucssesfuly picking image from gallry but when im picking image from google photos application crashed again and again

**OnClickListener**

```
      binding.cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openTools = 1;
                age = "";
                gender = "";
                emotion = "";
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    openCamera();
                } else {
                    requestPermission();
                }

            }
        });
        binding.galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openTools = 2;
                age = "";
                gender = "";
                emotion = "";
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    openGallery();
                } else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }

        });
```

**Permissions**

```
public static String[] storge_permissions = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    public static String[] storge_permissions_33 = {
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
    };

    public static String[] permissions() {
        String[] p;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            p = storge_permissions_33;
        } else {
            p = storge_permissions;
        }
        return p;
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            return checkPermissionAboveQ();
        } else {
            return checkPermissionBelowQ();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private boolean checkPermissionAboveQ() {
        for (String permission : storge_permissions_33) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkPermissionBelowQ() {
        for (String permission : storge_permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions(), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (openTools == 1) {
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            openCamera();
                        } else {
                            requestPermission();
                        }
                    } else if (openTools == 2) {
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            openGallery();
                        } else {
                            requestPermission();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!checkPermission()) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle(R.string.permission_recuierd)
                                .setMessage(R.string.this_app_requires)
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.go_to_settings, (dialog, which) -> openAppSettings())
                                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                })
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (checkPermission()) {
            if (openTools == 1) {
                openCamera();
            } else if (openTools == 2) {
                openGallery();
            }
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.permission_recuierd)
                    .setMessage(R.string.this_app_requires)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.go_to_settings, (dialog, which) -> openAppSettings())
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

**Intents For Pick Image**

```
 private void openAppSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
```

**Other Functions**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
            if (mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("image/")) {
                // Selected item is an image
                file = new File(getFullPathFromUri(uri));
                try {
                    compFile = compressImage(file, 800, 800);
                    System.out.println("compFile Gallery: " + compFile);
                    uploadImage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Selected item is not an image (e.g., video)
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pleas_select_an_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            // Save the captured image to a file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File imageFile = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", storageDir);
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                file = imageFile;
                compFile = compressImage(file, 800, 800);
                System.out.println("compFileCam: " + compFile);


                uploadImage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private String getFullPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
        String fullPath = null;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                fullPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private File compressImage(File originalFile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) throws IOException {
        // Load the original image into a Bitmap
        Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Calculate the new dimensions for the compressed image
        int originalWidth = originalBitmap.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = originalBitmap.getHeight();
        int newWidth, newHeight;
        if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            newWidth = maxWidth;
            newHeight = (int) (originalHeight * ((float) maxWidth / originalWidth));
        } else {
            newHeight = maxHeight;
            newWidth = (int) (originalWidth * ((float) maxHeight / originalHeight));
        }

        // Create a scaled bitmap with the new dimensions
        Bitmap compressedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

        // Create a new file for the compressed image
        File compressedFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "compressed_image.jpg");

        // Compress the bitmap and save it to the new file
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(compressedFile);
        compressedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // Recycle the original and compressed bitmaps to free up memory
        originalBitmap.recycle();
        compressedBitmap.recycle();

        return compressedFile;
    }
```

**ERORS**

```
uri Result content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A847dc8ca-ba93-419d-9529-c1b50b72e932/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/2047781671
AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey:/local%3A847dc8ca-ba93-419d-9529-c1b50b72e932/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/2047781671 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A847dc8ca-ba93-419d-9529-c1b50b72e932/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/2047781671} }} to activity {com.face.scanner.age.calculator.detector/com.face.age.detector.FaceAgeDetectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4491)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4533)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:283)
                                                                                                        at com.face.age.detector.FaceAgeDetectionActivity.onActivityResult(FaceAgeDetectionActivity.java:292)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
```

i want to pick image from Google Photos also but giving crashes with this code but picking image from gallery and camera sucessfully. when we chose image from photos it gives null poitnter Exception.